# Enter key on softkeyboard not triggering event when pressed

Tags: java, android

I want to trigger the searching when I press enter from softkeyboard, but it isn't working. It works fine if the key enter is pressed on a physical keyboard (through emulator). Perhaps I'm the wrong listener?

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    readJson();
    final View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    EditText search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                    actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                    actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO ||
                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                            event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
                    int found=0;
                   String inserted = v.getText().toString();
                    for(int i=0;i<city_list.size();i++){
                        if(inserted.equalsIgnoreCase(city_list.get(i).get("name").toString())){
                            found=1;
                            TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_id);
                            id.setText(city_list.get(i).get("id").toString());
                            TextView lat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_lat);
                            lat.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lat").toString());
                            TextView lon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_long);
                            lon.setText(city_list.get(i).get("lon").toString());
                        }
                    }

                    if(found==0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "City not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    return true; // consume.
                }
            }
            return false; // pass on to other listeners.
        }
    });
```

Tried also:

```
search.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

Comment: Use setOnKeyListener ?

Comment: I tried that before but it's not working neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code to your `R.id.search_view`:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
android:inputType="text"
```